# Why do some languages return nil when a key is not in a dictionary, while Python throws an exception?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I am interested in learning the rationale behind the following behaviour:

In Ruby,

```
irb(main):003:0> dic = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}
irb(main):004:0> dic[:c]
=> nil
```

In Javascript:

```
> var dic = {a: 1, b: 2};
undefined
> dic['c']
undefined
```

Clojure:

```
user=> (def dic {:a 1 :b 2})
#'user/dic
user=> (:c dic)
nil
```

While in Python:

```
>>> dic = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> dic['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

I would like to know why Python's (default) behaviour is to raise an exception instead of returning some form of `nil` like the other languages listed above. I didn't see the answer in [the design faq.](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html) (I guess an equivalent question would be asking why the other languages do what they do, but Python seems to be the oddball in this respect.)

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. How would you distinguish a key that is not in the dictionary, and a key that is associated with `nil`?

Comment: If you want the same behaviour, use `dic.get('c')`.

Comment: also just because... different languages are, well, different

Comment: God, I love Python. My immediate reaction was "what language (except Javascript obviously) is stupid enough to return nil in that situation?" Well, now I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)(Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission):

> This common Python coding style assumes the **existence of valid keys** or
>   **attributes** and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This
>   clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many `try` and
>   `except` statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common
>   to many other languages such as C.

Answer (score 6):

From the Zen of Python (`import this`):

```
 Errors should never pass silently.
 Unless explicitly silenced.
```

Meaning, a key not found is treated as an error, unless you explicitly code for it, e.g. by catching `KeyError` or using the `dict.get(key, default)` method.

Python was explicitly designed to be very explicit in this and (most) other respects.